# nginx + passenger + sqlite3 on Pi getting 502 bad gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, passenger

n00b to RoR here. I'm moving an application from my mac onto my raspberry pi using git clone. after the clone took place, i did 
`bundle install`

then i installed passenger and nginx:

```
gem install passenger
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

setup the database and seeded it

```
rvmsudo rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

then setup nginx to load on boot following a guide. copy/pasted the nginx file

```
sudo cp /var/www/monsterpi/nginx /etc/init.d/
```

made changes in the configuration file

```
sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

to look like this

```
    server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name monsterpi.kendrickcoleman.c0m; 
    passenger_enabled on; 
    root /var/www/monsterpi/public; 
    error_log /var/log/nginxerror.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginxaccess.log;
     }
```

then ran these commands to finish it up

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d nginx defaults
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

when i go to my server at monsterpi.kendrickcoleman.c0m, it works. I can see my static homepage. however, when i add or make an edit to a database entry, i get a 502 Bad Gateway | nginx/1.4.2 error page.

when reviewing the production.log, passenger is loading the edit page
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.355495 #2619]  INFO -- : Started GET "/rasberry_pis/1/edit" for 192.168.10.112 at 2013-09-20 04:19:06 +0000
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.373544 #2619]  INFO -- : Processing by RasberryPisController#edit as HTML
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.376013 #2619]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.509689 #2619]  INFO -- :   Rendered rasberry_pis/_form.html.erb (100.2ms)
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.521555 #2619]  INFO -- :   Rendered rasberry_pis/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (114.4ms)
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.545626 #2619]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (9.1ms)
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.555961 #2619]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (5.1ms)
I, [2013-09-20T04:19:06.561765 #2619]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 182ms (Views: 158.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)

As soon as I press the Submit button, the passenger log doesn't contain any more entries. The 502 Bad Gateway page appears. The nginxerror.log does populate with an entry every time i click submit.

2013/09/20 04:19:11 [error] 2253#0: *17 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.112, server: monsterpi.kendrickcoleman.c0m, request: "POST /rasberry_pis/1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.2207/generation-0/request:", host: "monsterpi.kendrickcoleman.c0m", referrer: "http://monsterpi.kendrickcoleman.c0m/rasberry_pis/1/edit"

i've changed my database.yml to have sqlite3 point to the absolute path

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: /var/www/monsterpi/db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

everything works perfectly with  `rails s -e production` 
i've googled around and can't seem to find an answer. any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: would it be possible to start your application on raspi in development mode? That will show more descriptive error messages. Can you load a page which has no database logic but is preprocessed by rails? like an `erb` file (sitting in `app/views/...`)?

Answer (score 1):

so after dealing with this, i ended up scraping passenger and moving to thin. I think the issues lies with the Raspberry Pi not having enough available memory. In addition, thin is much easier to  configure. Using thin, i had this running in a matter of minutes. I'm now using this type of setup for all my rails applications that need to be deployed on their own servers.

I've detailed the steps on how to create a nginx + thin configuration on my project home page. Start off on step 3 where I talk about installing the thin rails server. Change the configurations for your own purposes depending upon how many thin instances you plan on using.

http://kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Ruby-on-Rails-Projects/introducing-the-monsterremote-for-the-monstershield.html